# Nodejs Exec Function Doesnt Work For Multiline Shell Scripts

Tags: node.js, shell, exec, child-process

i am trying to get nodejs to execute a shell script programatically if a certain url is called.

i can call single line unix commands like "echo hello-world". and this behaves how i expect (output to stdout "hello-world").

```
import { exec } from 'child-process';
exec('echo hello-world', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }

    console.log('Deployment finished!');
    return stdout;
})
```

but i want to run a script with this command. e.g.

shell-script.sh (which is made executable `chmod +x shell-script.sh`)

```
echo hello-world

ls -la
```

and nodejs:

```
exec('./shell-script.sh', ...)
```

but this does not work in nodejs. i tried the same script in my desktop terminal and it works fine.

i then test the same with only the first line. (`echo hello-world`), which worked but i dont know why.

i then modified my shell script to:

```
echo hello-world &&\
ls -la
```

**note:** i used `&&\` to make the command into one line when executed.

this worked! but is there a way to execute a shell script with multiples lines without having to add `&&\` at the end of each line?

Comment: Have you tried `exec('sh shell-scrip.sh')`?

Comment: Made it an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score -1):

So apparently it can be `exec('sh shell-scrip.sh')`.