# How to run multiline commands in NodeJS with child_process.exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

**NOTE:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995199/nodejs-exec-function-doesnt-work-for-multiline-shell-scripts) did not help me.

I'm trying to create a task runner for [Atom](https://atom.io) and I've come to the point of running multi-line shell scripts. But

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
child_process.exec(
    `rm -rf something
         another
         directory`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        /*...*/
    },
)
```

Lead to node to think that `another` and `directory` were commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is

```js
child_process.exec(
    yourCommand.replace(/\n/g, "\\\n"),
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        /*...*/
    }
);
```

Which will modify all newlines to have a backslash before the newline.

---

For Windows, it would be very similar but replacing all new lines with  `^\n` instead of `\\\n`:

```js
child_process.exec(
    yourCommand.replace(/\n/g, "^\n"),
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        /*...*/
    }
);
```

Comment: True, does not work on windows, but nicely on unix. Do you have an idea, how to resolve this issue on windows?

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/how-to-write-a-multiline-command), it seems to me that you can do `yourCommand.replace((/\n/g, "^\n")` on Windows.